# LNK2091 error for OCIObjectGetAttr and OCIObjectSetAttr

Tags: c, windows, linker-errors, static-linking, oracle-call-interface

I have a small Windows x64 Console program statically linked to oci.lib (12.1.0.1.0) which was working well so far until I tried to use the APIs OCIObjectGetAttr/OCIObjectSetAttr. Now my program gives the following Linker errors:

- Error    19  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl OCIObjectSetAttr(struct OCIEnv *,struct OCIError *,void *,void *,struct OCIType *,unsigned char const * *,unsigned int const *,unsigned int,unsigned int const *,unsigned int,short,void const *,void const *)" (?OCIObjectSetAttr@@YAHPEAUOCIEnv@@PEAUOCIError@@PEAX2PEAUOCIType@@PEAPEBEPEBII5IFPEBX6@Z) referenced in function "bool __cdecl dump_object(struct OCIEnv *,struct OCIError *,struct OCISvcCtx *,void *,void *,void *)" (?dump_object@@YA_NPEAUOCIEnv@@PEAUOCIError@@PEAUOCISvcCtx@@PEAX33@Z)
- Error    20  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl OCIObjectGetAttr(struct OCIEnv *,struct OCIError *,void *,void *,struct OCIType *,unsigned char const * *,unsigned int const *,unsigned int,unsigned int const *,unsigned int,short *,void * *,void * *,struct OCIType * *)" (?OCIObjectGetAttr@@YAHPEAUOCIEnv@@PEAUOCIError@@PEAX2PEAUOCIType@@PEAPEBEPEBII5IPEAFPEAPEAX7PEAPEAU3@@Z) referenced in function "bool __cdecl dump_object(struct OCIEnv *,struct OCIError *,struct OCISvcCtx *,void *,void *,void *)" (?dump_object@@YA_NPEAUOCIEnv@@PEAUOCIError@@PEAUOCISvcCtx@@PEAX33@Z)

Commenting only those two APIs fixes the linker error. I made sure that nothing in project is changed apart from adding the two OCIObjectGetAttr and OCIObjectSetAttr API calls. Other OCIObject* APIs are linking. dumpbin /exports oci.lib shows that OCIObjectGetAttr and OCIObjectSetAttr are exported from the oci.lib.

What am I missing?

Stuck with this for quite a while. Google/Community search hasn't helped either.

Please help.

TIA

NB: [Also posted in OTN](https://community.oracle.com/message/12457198#12457198) (https://community.oracle.com/message/12457198#12457198)
Please forgive duplicate posting in desperation

Comment: Are there any DLLs that the executable requires, or any additional external libraries that provide for those APIs?

Comment: @Ceann +1 for replying. Oracle says either dynamic link with oci.dll or static link with oci.lib. But I am mostly confused from Oracle docs always!

Comment: Try linking to oci.dll instead. If that doesn't work, I can't think of anything past redownloading the libraries --  I took a look around and, as you said, it doesn't seem like there are any other libraries that need to be present for this API to work.

Comment: @Ceann I will try dynamic linking to it. But my distribution was static linked. That will need to change if it works that way!

Comment: @Ceann Dynamic link also didn't work. Funny it always compiles in Linux. oci.lib is some kind of DLL template. I tried with both MT and MD flags. Nothing changed.

Comment: I assume you're compiling under MSVC? Try compiling under Cygwin or MinGW, maybe gcc will compile properly on Windows.

Comment: I can definitely try that with lot of work of course. So before I go that way, I would like to understand why only two sips won't link while others from same library does!

Comment: As for that, I honestly have no idea. The only thing I can think of is an error on Oracle's part when compiling the Windows libraries -- it seems very unlikely but there's no reason why only these two functions would complain about having declarations but no definitions.

Comment: Yeah that is what baffles me too. The only reason I can think of is the header file signature not matching. Is there a way to get the exported function signature from a library (.lib)?

Comment: Unfortunately that's outside my realm of expertise haha

Comment: Where did you get your oci.dll from? First, you can only dynamically link to OCI. On Windows, dynamic linking means linking statically oci.lib at build time, which is an "import library", that contains stubs to the OCI API functions, which transparently at runtime loads oci.dll and calls the appropriate function in there. Second, the demangled prototypes show "unsigned int" (ub4) instead of "const unsigned int" as the proto in the header and the doc at http://goo.gl/UlvpfR show it should be. Could be the demangler just drops the const though.

Comment: @ddevienne Thanks for replying. oci.dll is shipped within oracle instant client release zip. Mine is downloaded from [InstantClient Win x64](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html). Since my static linking fails (as in your second point) and since the difference of 'const' (in certain parameters) are between linker error and orid.h (or oracle doc) could this be somewhere in my project setting? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in orid.h, the following got me going. I was trying to link from C++ where as orid.h is missing the standard extern "C" block for linking from C++ like other oci header files.

Wrapping the content of orid.h within the following got me successfully compiling.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

Hope Oracle fixes it in their next instant client release :).

Thanks to [Ceann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3680119/ceann) and [ddevienne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103724/ddevienne) for helping me to narrow down.